# Options Menu not displayed in android

Tags: android, menu, android-optionsmenu

I have written one application. I want to show the settings option on the login screen of an application. Now i have an activity LoginActivity as shown below

```
class LoginActivity extends BaseLoginActivity
{   
 showLoginDialog();
/* some code here*/
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    populateMenu(menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

protected void populateMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, SETTINGS, Menu.NONE, "Settings").setIcon(
            android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case SETTINGS:
            startSettingActiviy();
            return (true);

    }

    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

public void startSettingActiviy() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

 /* some code here*/
}
```

when i press on the menu option i cannot see the menu. I tried to debug the code, it is not even reaching the oncreateOptionsMenu function. Please let me know what is missing here.

Comment: try setHasOptionmenu(true); in oncreate

Comment: could You please show you optionsMenu.xml?

Comment: @RahulPatil it says that setHasOptionmenu(true) function is not found.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i am not using menu.xml, instead using layout interface format.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
populateMenu(menu);
return true;
}
```

and this too

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case SETTINGS:
        startSettingActiviy();
        return (true);

}

return true;
}
```

hope this will help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

> ```
>  @Override
>   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
>       populateMenu(menu);
>       return true;
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` instead

Also,
Minimum SDK version could be the cause. If you reduce it to 13-, you should probably see the menu show up again. Good article on this subject: [POST](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html)